Was Frege the first to claim that natural language is logically inconsistent?
Gottlob Frege claimed that natural language was logically inconsistent. After him, most academics seem to have bought the idea, most prominently Bertrand Russell, Rudolf Carnap, Alfred Tarski and Peter Strawson.
My question is: Was Frege the first self-proclaimed logician to claim (publicly) that natural language is logically inconsistent?
Thank you for any scholarly reference.

Nota
Clearly, there is one intemperate user here. Presumably the downvoting of my otherwise perfectly interesting question is for qualifying Frege, Russell, Carnap, Tarski and Strawson as "self-proclaimed logicians". Yet, this is factually true. Some people don't like the real world and take refuge in their imagination. It doesn't work.
When you write authoritatively on logic, as all these people did, you implicitly but clearly define yourself as a logician. There is no harm in this, but we all keep our own opinion as to who is what exactly, and my informed opinion is that these people didn't understand logic and so were not really logicians. Given this, I cannot possibly countenance calling them "logicians", at least not without the appropriate caveat.
Edit
Some posters here deny that the academics I mentioned have said that natural language was logically inconsistent, so here is what Richard L. Epstein says:

XXII. The Liar Paradox
But Alfred Tarski, 1933, held that any language that contains predicates and words that can be used to formulate a liar paradox will necessarily be inconsistent. In particular, any ordinary language such as English, he argued, is inherently inconsistent, for it contains the predicate ‘— is true’ and the means to name its own sentences.
-- Richard L. Epstein, Classical Mathematical Logic (2006)
Published by Princeton University Press
https://doi.org/10.1515/9781400841554.437

Google Books' blurb on Richard L Epstein:

Richard L Epstein received his B.A. summa cum laude from the University of Pennsylvania, and his Ph.D. from the University of California, Berkeley. He held a post-doctoral fellowship in mathematics and philosophy at Victoria University of Wellington, New Zealand, and was a Fulbright Fellow to Brazil and a National Academy of Sciences Scholar to Poland. He is the author of "Propositional Logics" and, with Walter Carnielli, "Computability". He is now the Head of the Advanced Reasoning Forum.


Frege developed (1879) the concept of Begriffsschrift a concept writing or concept notation identified as "a formula language, modeled on that of arithmetic, for pure thought." Frege's motivation for developing his formal approach to logic resembled Leibniz's motivation for his calculus ratiocinator.

Calculus ratiocinator or Characteristica universalis: "is a universal and formal language imagined by Gottfried Leibniz able to express mathematical, scientific, and metaphysical concepts. Leibniz thus hoped to create a language usable within the framework of a universal logical calculation."

Relevant: Jean Van Heijenoort, Logic as Calculus and Logic as Language (1967)

Maybe René Descartes first claimed so since he doubted everything except his famous cogito?...

where did he claim that natural language is inconsistent? never heard of that

@Speakpigeon I didn't downvote you but I think your question would get more support, and perhaps be more likely to yield a useful answer, if you remove the "Nota". I think the "Nota" distracts from the good question that you are asking.

Theories can be consistent or inconsistent. Languages are just languages. The only people who have claimed that natural languages are inconsistent are trivialists who think that all statements are both true and false. Perhaps you are referring to the fact that natural languages are capable of stating semantic paradoxes? If so, I don't see what the question is.

@user509184 So, you think it's a good question and you decided to downvote it because you were distracted by the nota? Ok, good. - 2. I added a nota because someone had downvoted my question, so this one certainly didn't downvote because he was distracted by the nota.

@Speakpigeon No, as I wrote, I did not downvote you. And yes, I think there is a good question you are asking.

@user509184 "I did not downvote you" Sorry for having misread your comment.

You claim that all those people (Frege up to Strawson) claimed that natural languages are inconsistent? What does it mean to say something like that? Could you please (1) give at least one (referenced) quote from the writings of one of them and (2) if the reference doesn't literally make the same claim, explain why you believe your interpretation is correct?

Two/more propositions can be inconsistent. Is language such?

@Hudjefa It is acceptable. See, for example, Tarski's "The Semantic Conception of Truth: and the Foundations of Semantics".

Tarski definitely did not claim that ordinary language is inconsistent. This is what he writes (in the above article): "At first blush it would seem that this language satisfies both assumptions (I) and (II), and that therefore it must be inconsistent. But actually the case is not so simple. Our everyday language is certainly not one with an exactly specified structure. We do not know precisely, which expressions are sentences, and we know even to a smaller degree which sentences are to be taken as assertible. Thus the problem of consistency has no exact meaning with respect to this language.

@mudskipper what Hudjefa asks is whether a language may be said to be consistent/inconsistent.

Thanks for the clarification @TankutBeygu - I had not read all comments carefully enough.

I'll jot down a brief answer with a view to expand on it later.
The natural language is logically inconsistent/semantically opaque/ambiguous and the like, in essence, add up to the idea and question of perfect language. Though the views and ideals gathered under the heading of perfect language may seem quite divergent one from another, however, they are intrinsically connected by the nature of language —this point requires to be argued separately, so I shall not delve into it.
The most comprehensive history of the subject, so far as I'm aware, is The Search for the Perfect Language (as the title of its English translation) by Umberto Eco. The contents of the book that I've inserted below may give an idea about the roots and the extensiveness of the subject (though it touches upon the undertaking of formal languages slightly).


Eco marks the beginning of the project of a perfect language with Dante (p. 34):

The first occasion on which the world of medieval Christianity had to
confront a systematic project for a perfect language was the De
vulgari eloquentia (hereafter DVE) of Dante Alighieri, written
presumably between 1303 and
1305.
Dante's text opens with an observation which, obvious though it may
be, is still fundamental for us: there is a multitude of vulgar
tongues, all of them are natural languages, and all are opposed to
Latin - which is a universal but artificial grammar.

But it must be Raymond Lull to be the first that sought a non-natural solution (p. 53):

It was among the Franciscans that all of the earlier strands converged
in his Ars magna, which Lull conceived as a system for a perfect
language with which to convert the infidels. The language was to be a
universal; it was to be articulated at the level of expression in a
universal mathematics of combination; its level of content was to
consist of a network of universal ideas, held by all peoples, which
Lull himself would devise.

No doubt it is Leibniz who occupies an exceptional place in the course the idea takes.
The other notable publications I can cite are Renaissance Truths: Humanism, Scholasticism and the Search for the Perfect Language by Alan R. Perreiah and Logic and the Art of Memory: The Quest for a Universal Language (as the title of its English translation) by Paolo Rossi.
The papers "Logic and the Myth of the Perfect Language" by Marco Carapezza and Marcello D’Agostino and "The Language of Thought as a Logically Perfect Language" by Andrea Bianchi focus on the formal language aspect that begins with Leibniz.

Vow! Quite a resource list! Tnx!

Glad to be of help.

I hadn't read your post properly. Would orthographical inconsistencies count as evidence that language is inconsistent? E.g. "argue" (R-GYU) and "tongue" (TUNG)?

As for Tarski's paper, that would be merely a surface matter; it would be frivolous to take it into consideration. But as for the endeavour of perfect language, it might be a sign of that natural language is prone to mislead.

The term 'consistent' and the predicate 'is consistent' is normally applied to theories - considered as well-defined sets of propositions (assertions of fact or theorems) that are assumed (or proven) to be true.
Natural languages are not sets of propositions. So, it makes no sense to claim that they would be inconsistent. (By the same token, it also does not make sense to claim that they would be consistent.)
None of the mathematicians, logicians and philosophers mentioned in the question ever claimed that a natural language is identical to a set of propositions or even that it could be reduced to such a set. None of them ever claimed that natural language as such is inconsistent or that a natural language is inconsistent (in the above sense of logically consistent). I dare to claim this, even though I have, of course, not read all of their work, because such a claim would simply be silly and absurd; if the OP provides a reference that convincingly refutes this, I will stand corrected and humbly admit that I was wrong.
In The Semantic Conception of Truth Tarski, analyzing the paradox of the liar, speaks of the "inconsistency of semantically closed languages" (basically defined as formal languages in which the paradox of the liar would be expressible) and he considers the question whether or not "everyday language" should be seen as semantically closed (and thus inconsistent). He writes:

The languages (either the formalized languages or — what is more frequently the case — the portions of everyday language) which are used in scientific discourse do not have to be semantically closed. This is obvious in case linguistic phenomena and, in particular, semantic notions do not enter in any way into the subject-matter of a science; for in such a case the language of this science does not have to be provided with any semantic terms at all. However, we shall see in the next section how semantically closed languages can be dispensed with even in those scientific discussions in which semantic notions are essentially involved.

Immediately followed by these crucial, careful observations:

The problem arises as to the position of everyday language with regard to this point. At first blush it would seem that this language satisfies both assumptions (I) and (II), and that therefore it must be inconsistent. But actually the case is not so simple. Our everyday language is certainly not one with an exactly specified structure. We do not know precisely, which expressions are sentences, and we know even to a smaller degree which sentences are to be taken as assertible. Thus the problem of consistency has no exact meaning with respect to this language. We may at best only risk the guess that a language whose structure has been exactly specified and which resembles our everyday language as closely as possible would be inconsistent.


A sensible answer!

Logical inconsistency (or if you prefer logical incoherence) can be said of propositions, arguments, or claimants, but it is not said widely or generally said of natural languages. Under the Saussurean notion of langue and parole, language is roughly divided into its imputed grammar and lexicon (langue), which is a description of its syntax and meaning, and its use by speakers (parole). The logical aspect of the language maybe described by the logical semantics of the langue, but the langue itself does not assert, and therefore, strictly speaking does not apply truth conditions to constructs.
For there to be logical inconsistency in a language, that requires a speaker construct propositions and assign them truth values, and is generally called assertoric force in the philosophy of language. Thus having two propositions P1 and P2 contradict each other makes the language logically inconsistent, or having arguments A1 and A2 contradict each other makes the language logically inconsistent, or having a person accept A1 and A2 given their contradictory claims makes the language logically inconsistent, but these are concrete instances of language use, and thus means the aforementioned use of 'language' has the sense of parole and not langue.
There are still some thinkers who maintain such a thesis anyway. Such a position is called trivialism. From WP:

Trivialism is the logical theory that all statements (also known as propositions) are true and that all contradictions of the form "p and not p" (e.g. the ball is red and not red) are true. In accordance with this, a trivialist is a person who believes everything is true.

While clearly a radical and minority position, according to the article, it was considered briefly perhaps by Aristotle himself. From the article:

Luis Estrada-González in "Models of Possiblism and Trivialism" has interpreted Aristotle's Metaphysics Book IV as such: "A family of arguments between 1008a26 and 1007b12 of the form 'If trivialism is right, then X is the case, but if X is the case then all things are one. But it is impossible that all things are one, so trivialism is impossible.' ... these Aristotelian considerations are the seeds of virtually all subsequent suspicions against trivialism: Trivialism has to be rejected because it identifies what should not be identified, and is undesirable from a logical point of view because it identifies what is not identical, namely, truth and falsehood."

As such, it would seem that some considerations of natural languages as inherently inconsistent would go back to the Ancient Greeks.

Imagine a language that has developed such a grammar and vocabulary that, when followed obediently, it impels its speakers to contradictions and fallacies. What would you say of such a language?

@TankutBeygu Interesting question. Certainly, it wouldn't be found among natural languages. But, certainly an artificial grammar could be constructed to generate nothing but WFF that evaluate as contradictions. I'll edit my answer to clarify I was referring to the natural languages, and any reader witnesses your useful technical objection for consideration. :D Thanks!

@TankutBeygu - What do you mean by "impels" and "followed obediently"? Even to think about "grammar" as a system of rules - that thought is in itself a model, an idealization of actual language use, the actual processes of communication and creating "meaning". If it is taken as "the truth" then we'd be robots - even simpler than ChatGPT - and any language change would become inexplicable. But in the thought experiment - if that's all there is (as you posit it), then such a language could biologically never arise, and if posited as already there, never survive, since the speakers could not.

It's really a matter of degree, imo. It's an (almost? complete?) empirical fact that certain ideas are fostered by grammar. Just look at translatability between certain arguments in Western philosophy and in Chinese, for instance. Look at the historical development of both ideas (and problems) in tandem with particular languages and cultures. So, there may be some inconsistencies expressible in this or that language - But that doesn't make the language as a whole inconsistent...

@mudskipper such aspects of natural language are philosophically and linguistically too broad and vexed, while the question is history-oriented. Jody Azzouni's papers on his semantic trivialism ("the view that natural languages are logically inconsistent") may offer a glimpse into them. See, for instance, his "Inconsistency in Natural Languages"; also, Matti Eklund's paper "Inconsistent Languages". I've seen unanswered questions on trivialism in general; supplying answers to them might provide helpful discussion

@TankutBeygu Thanks for the link to the paper. Trivialism is a radical position I've seen in print a few times but never investigated. Of course, I find myself gravitating towards Priest's quotation in the article: 'Graham Priest considers trivialism untenable: "a substantial case can be made for dialetheism; belief in [trivialism], though, would appear to be grounds for certifiable insanity".'

I am respectful, however, of Quine and his notion of underdetermination. It seems to me that that a logician could argue trivialism if he refused to accept the utility of the a correspondent theory of truth and turn a blind eye to the evolutionary function of language.

@speakpigeon And if you excuse the fact that trivialism is a neologism that can be applied retroactively, perhaps Aristotle on the historically oriented inquiry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivialism#Aristotle

@TankutBeygu - Thanks for the links. I only very recently came to know some of the work of Azzouni. Not terribly impressed by him - but deserves attention.

Perhaps in the majority of instances, 'trivialism' is an unnecessarily strong name for the ideas intended, causing an impression something like a defence of solipsism would give. Besides, the basis of trivialism (metaphysical/linguistic/mathematical etc.) should be sufficiently clarified.


natural language is logically inconsistent?

I think it is a mistake to look at this question literally.
The language and the written word create inconsistencies in our understanding of reality. They have a power to turn lies into truth, to create fiction that self fulfills into reality. Fictional writing is the biggest threat to traditional philosophy.

The OP has not really tried to explain how they take this question, but has also not given any indication that it should not be taken literally.
A basic tenet of analytical philosophy (which roughly started with Russell and Wittgenstein) is that ordinary language (=grammatical patterns in the normal use of a particular natural language) can tempt us to think about conceptual puzzles in particular, unfounded, incorrect ways. If this tenet is true, then grammar can create false problems and misguided, false or essentially nonsensical ideas. Is that what you also mean by "fictional writing"?

Well, come to think of it there are inconsistencies in (the English) language at the orthographical level.
For example,
"Argue" (R-GYU) vs. "tongue" (TUNG).
The plural of "mouse" is "mice", but the plural of "house" is not "hice"
The past tense of "talk" is "talked", of ""paint" is "painted", but that of "run" is "ran" and "go" is "went".

Yes, but the language of logic is the language of thought and that is German, of course, as every real logician knows.  The only little awkardness in German is that der Begriff Pferd ist kein Begriff.

When you translate the perfectly true sentence "Dieser Satz ist ein Deustcher Satz" into English it becomes "This sentence is a German sentence" -- which is patently false. This proves, once again, that German is the logically perfect language and that English is a perfectly illogical language. QED.

@mudskipper Ganz witsig! Aber Sie sollen lesen: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantifier_variance Also kann mann nicht die perfekte Ontologie oder Logik finden. Es tut mir leid.

Danke :) You must to learn besser Germanic (Teutonic, as my high-school English teacher used to say), dear @JD.

Could the inconsistencies above be logical inconsistencies instead of just being a lack of pattern, with exceptions to word transformations, in this case temporally and quantitatively. We can't, e.g. do math if there's no pattern.
